# How to use secret manager in creating DMS target endpoint for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager, aws-dms

How do we create a [DMS endpoint for RDS using Terraform by providing the Secret Manager ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.html#security_iam_secretsmanager) to fetch the credentials? I looked at the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dms_endpoint) but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently [an open feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18123) for DMS to natively use secrets manager to connect to your RDS instance. This has [a linked pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19040) that initially adds support for PostgreSQL and Oracle RDS instances for now but is currently unreviewed so it's hard to know when that functionality may be released.

If you aren't using automatic secret rotation (or can rerun Terraform after the rotation) and don't mind the password being stored in the state file but still want to use the secrets stored in AWS Secrets Manager then you could have Terraform retrieve the secret from Secrets Manager at apply time and use that to configure the DMS endpoint using the username and password combination instead.

A basic example would look something like this:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
}

resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "example" {
  certificate_arn             = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
  database_name               = "test"
  endpoint_id                 = "test-dms-endpoint-tf"
  endpoint_type               = "source"
  engine_name                 = "aurora"
  extra_connection_attributes = ""
  kms_key_arn                 = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:key/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
  password                    = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string)["password"]
  port                        = 3306
  server_name                 = "test"
  ssl_mode                    = "none"

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }

  username = "test"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcor for the answer, I will give it a try.